How can i fix the column view in flex?
How can I fix the visibility of my columns in flex?
I have a problem when creating a fairly simple slider in JS, that my columns even though they have opacity 0; etc still take up their space. If I give them display: none; via a script I spoil the animation on the transform. I would like to have only 5 divs visible at a time.  Anyone know how I can achieve this?
What I want:

What I have:

Why:



const players = document.querySelectorAll('.player');
let currentIndex = Math.floor(players.length / 2);
let isAnimating = false;

function updatePlayers() {
    if (isAnimating) return;
    isAnimating = true;

    const totalPlayers = players.length;
    const maxVisible = 2;

    players.forEach((player) => {
        player.classList.remove('active', 'prev1', 'prev2', 'next1', 'next2');
        player.style.opacity = '0';
        player.style.transform = 'scale(0.7)';
    });

    for (let i = -maxVisible; i <= maxVisible; i++) {
        let index = (currentIndex + i + totalPlayers) % totalPlayers;
        let player = players[index];

        if (player) {
            if (i === 0) {
                player.classList.add('active');
                player.style.opacity = '1';
                player.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
            } else {

                let scale = 1 - Math.abs(i) * 0.1;
                let opacity = 1 - Math.abs(i) * 0.2;
                player.style.opacity = opacity.toString();
                player.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;

                if (i < 0) {
                    player.classList.add('prev1');
                } else {
                    player.classList.add('next1'); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    const activePlayer = players[currentIndex];
    const container = document.querySelector('.player-container');
    const containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
    const activeCardWidth = activePlayer.offsetWidth;

    const activePlayerRect = activePlayer.getBoundingClientRect();
    const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();

    const offset = (containerWidth / 2) - (activePlayerRect.left - containerRect.left + activeCardWidth / 2);

    container.style.transform = `translateX(${offset}px)`;
    container.style.transition = 'transform 0.3s ease';

    setTimeout(() => {
        isAnimating = false;
    }, 300);
}




function prevSlide() {
    if (isAnimating) return;
    currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + players.length) % players.length;
    updatePlayers();
}

function nextSlide() {
    if (isAnimating) return;
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % players.length;
    updatePlayers();
}

updatePlayers();
.for-player {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 80%;
}

.player {
  width: 18%;
  height: 90%;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: scale(0.7) translateX(0);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.player.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) translateX(0);
  z-index: 3;
}

.player.prev1,
.player.next1 {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform: scale(0.9);
  z-index: 2;
}

.player.prev2,
.player.next2 {
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  z-index: 1;
}

.player-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.player::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

.player p {
  text-align: left;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.player p:first-child {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.player p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 0;
  line-height: 1.25;
}

.player p:last-child {
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.player.active p:first-child {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.player.active p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.arrow-left,
.arrow-right {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

.arrow-left {
  left: 10px;
}

.arrow-right {
  right: 10px;
}
       <div class="for-player">
    <div class="arrow-left" onclick="prevSlide()">
        <img style="width: 60%;" src="css/photo/left-arrow-2.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="player-container">
    <div style="background-image: url(css/photo/zawodnik1.webp);" class="player">
            <p>Player</p>
            <p>1</p>
            <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pellentesque id lacus non ultrices. Nunc mollis ipsum at iaculis hendrerit. Aliquam nec varius massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuad</p>
        </div>
    <div style="background-image: url(css/photo/zawodnik2.webp);" class="player">
            <p>Player</p>
            <p>2</p>
            <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pellentesque id lacus non ultrices. Nunc mollis ipsum at iaculis hendrerit. Aliquam nec varius massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuad</p>
        </div>
        <div class="player">
            <p>Player</p>
            <p>3</p>
            <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pellentesque id lacus non ultrices. Nunc mollis ipsum at iaculis hendrerit. Aliquam nec varius massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuad</p>
        </div>
        <div class="player">
            <p>Player</p>
            <p>4</p>
            <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pellentesque id lacus non ultrices. Nunc mollis ipsum at iaculis hendrerit. Aliquam nec varius massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuad</p>
        </div>
        <div class="player">
            <p>Player</p>
            <p>5</p>
            <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pellentesque id lacus non ultrices. Nunc mollis ipsum at iaculis hendrerit. Aliquam nec varius massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuad</p>
        </div>
        <div class="player">
            <p>Player</p>
            <p>6</p>
            <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pellentesque id lacus non ultrices. Nunc mollis ipsum at iaculis hendrerit. Aliquam nec varius massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuad</p>
        </div>
        <div class="player">
            <p>Player</p>
            <p>7</p>
            <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pellentesque id lacus non ultrices. Nunc mollis ipsum at iaculis hendrerit. Aliquam nec varius massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuad</p>
        </div>
        <div class="player">
            <p>Player</p>
            <p>8</p>
            <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pellentesque id lacus non ultrices. Nunc mollis ipsum at iaculis hendrerit. Aliquam nec varius massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuad</p>
        </div>
        <div class="player">
            <p>Player</p>
            <p>9</p>
            <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam pellentesque id lacus non ultrices. Nunc mollis ipsum at iaculis hendrerit. Aliquam nec varius massa. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuad</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="arrow-right" onclick="nextSlide()">
  
    </div>



Codepen: https://codepen.io/zjebee/pen/VwoMooG
Thank you in advance!

Can you make the whole slider wider — wider than the viewport — so that the extra items on each side are invisible because they are outside the viewport?

When the display property is added, the animation breaks down when there are 3,4,5,6,7 elements in the middle. Here, there are 2 elements on the left and right. To fix this, you need to fix your transform calculation. Because when these elements are in the middle and there are 2 elements on the left and right, the transform gives the same value. Thus, the animation breaks down. translateX is the part you need to focus on.

In order to show only five slides in the carousel, with the middle slide as the focus, you may tweak updatePlayers() to display the current slide and two adjacent slides (one or two “previous” and “next” slides) while the rest are hidden. Below is how the JavaScript and CSS is to be modified in order to limit the visible slides to just 5:
JavaScript (Limit Visible Slides to 5)
Set maxVisible to 2 so that two slides are shown before and after the visible one, making the function only style and class five elements.
const players = document.querySelectorAll(".player");
let currentIndex = Math.floor(players.length / 2);
let isAnimating = false;

function updatePlayers() {
  if (isAnimating) return;
  isAnimating = true;

  const totalPlayers = players.length;
  const maxVisible = 2; // Only show two slides on each side of the active slide

  players.forEach((player, index) => {
    player.classList.remove("active", "prev1", "prev2", "next1", "next2");
    player.style.opacity = "0";
    player.style.transform = "scale(0.7)";
    player.style.display = "none"; // Hide all players initially
  });

  // Show only the active slide and two slides on either side
  for (let i = -maxVisible; i <= maxVisible; i++) {
    const index = (currentIndex + i + totalPlayers) % totalPlayers;
    const player = players[index];

    if (player) {
      player.style.display = "block"; // Show only the five slides around the active one

      if (i === 0) {
        player.classList.add("active");
        player.style.opacity = "1";
        player.style.transform = "scale(1)";
      } else {
        const scale = 1 - Math.abs(i) * 0.1;
        const opacity = 1 - Math.abs(i) * 0.2;
        player.style.opacity = opacity.toString();
        player.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;

        if (i < 0) {
          player.classList.add(`prev${Math.abs(i)}`);
        } else {
          player.classList.add(`next${i}`);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Center the active slide in the container
  const activePlayer = players[currentIndex];
  const container = document.querySelector(".player-container");
  const containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
  const activeCardWidth = activePlayer.offsetWidth;

  const activePlayerRect = activePlayer.getBoundingClientRect();
  const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();

  const offset =
    containerWidth / 2 -
    (activePlayerRect.left - containerRect.left + activeCardWidth / 2);

  container.style.transform = `translateX(${offset}px)`;
  container.style.transition = "transform 0.3s ease";

  setTimeout(() => {
    isAnimating = false;
  }, 300);
}

function prevSlide() {
  if (isAnimating) return;
  currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + players.length) % players.length;
  updatePlayers();
}

function nextSlide() {
  if (isAnimating) return;
  currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % players.length;
  updatePlayers();
}

updatePlayers();

let me know how it turns out! If any adjustments are needed, I'm here to help.

I have 1 problem with this. There is no animation on the middle blocks, but there is teleportation, so the animation is not smooth
